# How do I redirect from my home page to my landing page upon opening the site

Tags: wordpress

I have not made a static page for my homepage. I used the 'latest posts option' for my home page. Now when I enter the URL to open my website it takes me to the 'latest posts' page as it is my homepage. Along the line I decided to create a landing page and display the landing page when the URL is typed in. But I cannot figure out a way to display the Landing page first instead of the Home Page.
eg
localhost/wptest opens my homepage and localhost/wptest/Land opens my landing page and there are links to home page on the landing page which takes me to localhost/wptest.
I am new to this. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a plugin to create a coming-soon page? Below some of them
[CMP - Coming Soon & Maintenance Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cmp-coming-soon-maintenance/)
[Minimal Coming Soon & Maintenance Mode – Coming Soon Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/minimal-coming-soon-maintenance-mode/)
[Coming Soon & Maintenance Mode Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nifty-coming-soon-and-under-construction-page/)

The Other option is to change the pages on `Settings / Reading`.
On this same page, you can define your posts page, or you can add an HTML link to your posts page in your landing page.
[image]